# как отправлять сообщение о запуске бота aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно отправлять человеку сообщение о запуске скрипта(бота) на python aiogram. Как это можно реализовать, думал как нибудь через обработчик текста/комманд, но так ничего и не придумал.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
async def on_startup(_):
    user_should_be_notified = 123123123123  # Ваш айди
    await bot.send_message(user_should_be_notified, 'Бот запущен')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```